# How to calculate the turnaround time (preemtive- Scheduling)

Tags: operating-system

Hey Folks I have this exercise for my exams:

Three process arrive at he exact same time (run time in brackets)

P1 (10) P2 (7) P3(4)

a)calculate the turnaroundtime of all single processes and the average turnaroundtime time of the 3 processes.

b) In which sequence should the processes be executed to reduce the average turnaround time?

Edit: I found a solution.
a) 10 + 17 + 21 = 48 / 3 = 16 sec average 
b) Shortest Job First: 
4 + 11 + 21 = 36/3 = 12 sec average

Comment: Actually it isnt for homework. It is preperation for my exams on friday.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what scheduling algorithm you use.

Let T(x) = "P(x)'s turnaround time"

```
FCFS:
T(a)=10-0=10
T(b)=10+7-0=17
T(c)=10+7+4-0=21
Average turnaround time=48/3=16

SJF:
T(a)=4+7+10-0=21
T(b)=4+7-0=11
T(c)=4-0=4
Average turnaround time=36/3=12
```

You can also practice SRTF/RR/priority/Multilevel queue/M.F.Q Scheduleing

And draw Gantt chart and calculate average waiting time.

You can also practice RM algorithm and EDF algorithm which are used in realtime systems.